# .xyz domain no direct access when accessed from Address Bar in mobile

Tags: domains, browsers

If I type my site address in my android browser, it simply will redirect to google, but if I do the same to .com domain, it will go directly to the website.

Why's google not making a distinction between .xyz and .com yet? Or is that an android issue? Is there anything I can configure in my domain or host, to make the browser identify it as a domain? That's very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

> Its not Google who is redirecting it. Its the browser.

Everyone knows .COM domains extension is the most important TLD and most browsers like Opera mini, UC browser, etc. has defaulted .COM domains if extension is not provided.

Nothing on your part that you can do to change it except perhaps wait for .XYZ extension to get more popular than .COM extension and those browser companies decide to change their default extension to .XYZ